# Android: get most recent intent

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I get the last intent sent to an activity?

The docs for `onNewIntent()` suggest I would need to do something like this:

```
class MyActivity {
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
        setIntent(intent);
        reactToIntentAndDoStuff()
        super.onNewIntent(Intent intent);
    }
    public void onCreate(){
        reactToIntentAndDoStuff()
        super.onCreate();
    }
    public void onResume(){
        reactToIntentAndDoStuff()
        super.onResume();
    }
    public void reactToIntentAndDoStuff(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }
}
```

Does this look about right? Or is there a better way? My activity's `launchMode` will be `singleTop`. It will need to react to the same Intent in more or less the same way, whether it's already instantiated or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the correct way :)
Please check if you really need to call reactToIntentAndDoStuff() in onResume() method. I think its not needed.

super.onCreate(); should be first line in onCreate() method.

getIntent() returns an Intent which was received when Activity launched first time. This does not update unless we call setIntent(newIntent) method.

Comment: my onNewIntent() never get called, would you please share with me some idea?