# getIntent, Can't get my activity to get the latest intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm sure this is a failure in  my understanding of intents but I have an ExpandableListView of items and when I click on an item it launches the first one OK but for each time after that it only launches the first one again no matter which on I click on. The request debugs as OK but the received intent always debugs as if the first one was sent. After a half a day stuck on it and Google failing me, I need some help.

Activity #1 Mainfest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.h17.gpm.ActivityToDoList"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.h17.gpm.TODO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Activity #1 Code

```
Intent launch = new Intent(ActivityToDoList.this, ActivityToDoEdit.class);
launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
launch.putExtra("Action._ID", a.get_ID());
Log.d("ACTIVITYLAUNCHTEST", "Launch["+a.get_ID()+"]");
startActivity(launch);
```

Activity #2 Mainfest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.h17.gpm.ActivityToDoEdit"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.h17.gpm.TODO.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Activity Code #2

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo_edit);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = null;
    if(i != null)
        extras = i.getExtras();
    if (extras != null){ 
        action_id = extras.getLong("Action._ID");
        Log.d("ACTIVITYLAUNCHTEST", "Receive["+action_id+"]");
    }
}
```

I've read from other posts that getIntent returns the first Intent so also tried

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){  
    Bundle extras = null;
    if(intent != null)
        extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null){ 
        action_id = extras.getLong("Action._ID");
        Log.d("ACTIVITYLAUNCHTEST", "Receive New Intent["+action_id+"]");
    }
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

I've also tried a lot of combinations of Intent Flags and Launch Modes in the Manifest but for the life of me the first time always comes up as

```
Launch[1]
Receive[1]
```

and the second time

```
Launch[2]
Receive[1]
```

and from then on no matter what value I send the activity launches with the first value, 1 and the onNewIntent never seems to fire.

The complete function that generates the intent

```
private void loadLists(){
    ExpandableListView expandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewToDoLists);
    expandableList.setClickable(true);
    adapter = new ActionListsExpandableAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
    expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            Action a = (Action) parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            if (startedForResult){
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("Action._ID", a.get_ID());
                data.putExtra("Action.SUBJECT", a.getSUBJECT());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }else{
                ActionList al = (ActionList) parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroup(groupPosition);
                Intent launch = new Intent(ActivityToDoList.this, ActivityToDoEdit.class);
                launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                launch.putExtra("Action._ID", a.get_ID());
                Log.d("ACTIVITYLAUNCHTEST", "Launching activity with intent for Action ID ["+a.get_ID()+"]");
                launch.putExtra("ActionList._ID", al.get_ID());
                launch.putExtra("ActionList.position", childPosition);
                startActivity(launch);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: getExtras() returns bundle which can set by putExtras(), here you are using putExtra().

Comment: Hi Neet, Maybe I misunderstood but I tried using i.getLongExtra("Action._ID", 0); rather then a Bundle and it still has the same result.

Comment: Can you show us more of the code which sends the `Intent`?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the full function that runs when you click on an item in the expandable list

Comment: what does `get_ID()` returns? You must be making any mistake there.

Comment: the getID returns the primary key of a sql table as a long.  The Log.d rules out the return values as the problem as it outputs launch 2 and receive 1

Answer (score 1):

May be this is a good reference for you.
To me it seems like `onNewIntent (with FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)` like onCreate will be called if app is not destroyed. Hope is helpful to you. It works for me in my case.

For further reference  see 
[Android: get most recent intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396272/android-get-most-recent-intent)